# Local Stack vs Call Stack

Tags: recursion, stack

On the matter of Recursion:

When you create a recursive function, you create a call stack. Ok, no problem; However, a comment on [this page](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) (look for comments by "LKM") triggered my curiosity (and google was no help):

- What is a local stack?
- Why would it be faster than a call stack?
- How would you actually implement it (pseudo-code, js/php/ruby/python are ok)?

Subsidiary question (might deserve another question, but I don't know on which (.*\.)?stack.*\.com to ask):

In these conversations about programming, I often see the "recursion" theme and how bad/newbie programmers don't grok it. I'm self-taught, and I never understood what the big fuss is all about. I use recursion a lot in my everyday coding, both for solving problems and sometimes just because I think they are beautiful. But these articles make me feel like maybe there is something there I just don't see. So:

- What's all the fuss about recursion? What's there not to grok?

Comment: I don't see any comments on that page by "LKM". A text search turns up one comment by "blkmage" and one response to his comment, but that's it.

Comment: @Mason I found the comments searching for "LKM".

Comment: Oh, nevermind. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "local" stack, as that comment uses it, means stack implicitly declared as a local variable. I would differentiate it from the call stack by calling it an "explicit" stack.

Iterating on an explicit stack can be faster than recursion in languages that don't support recursion related optimizations such as tail recursion. Or a language may have limited stack depth.

Here is a [good explanation with an example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/recursion-part-two-unrolling-a-recursive-function-with-an-explicit-stack) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: I don't understand the benefit of this. Whats wrong with using the call stack (other than stack overflows)?

Comment: @Pubby Often there is no benefit, especially if you are using a functional language with compiler optimizations related to recursion. If you are using a language like javascript, there can be performance benefits, though beware premature optimizations. An explicit stack can also be more elegant in some ways, a depth first traversal of a tree using an explicit stack can be changed into a breadth first traversal be replacing the stack with a queue.

Comment: For one thing, your heap (if you heap allocate the explicit stack) is a lot bigger than the call stack.  So you can go deeper.  Also if you bothered to rewrite a recursive algorithm into an iterative one with an explicit stack, you are often close enough so that with a minimum of additional effort you can manually wring out the tail-call optimization.  At that point you win.

Comment: you wrote "implicitly" but you meant "explicitly"

Answer (score 2):

LKM simply means a manually handled stack, for example a linked list where you push elements at the head and then pop them out again. It'd be faster because it's smaller, less data to shuffle around.

It's implemented by having a field in your struct that's a pointer (or reference if you wish) to the next element, and a head variable that's the top of the stack. When you push, you set the next pointer of your pushed element to the current value of the head variable, and then set the head variable to reference the pushed element. Popping does the inverse.

Another way to implement it, if you know the maximum stack of the stack, is to have a normal array and an index variable which tells where in the array the head is. That's actually how the recursion call stack is implemented, if you simplify it.

I believe most of the languages you mention above also have special constructs to treat arrays as stacks, usually called push/pop or shift/unshift.

Comment: How the hell is a linked list faster than a hardware call stack?

Comment: Well, it isn't necessarily, but it might be. If there's a stack frame that needs to be setup, and registers saved on the stack, then it most likely is.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using a local stack means "using a local variable, e.g. an array that is accessed like a stack", i.e. FIFO, as opposed to "making function calls, which create stack frames, each of which contains an int, all of which taken together contain the same values as your array would". It can be faster because you're avoiding the overhead of pushing and popping registers, setting up the local stack frame for each function invocation etc. Instead you're doing  just one memory allocation and that's it (and if you use `alloca` then your local stack really *is* on the call stack - `alloca` is essentially just an in dex increment, while `malloc` can involve all sorts of expensive operations).

The trade-off, as always, is that by making the machinery of the stack visible, the actual recursive structure of the algorithm is a lot less clear to many  people. Note that I say "many people" - some people naturally understand recursion and some don't. (I used to teach Scheme and Prolog to freshmen, and I'd say that very roughly a third of them do and two thirds don't.) Entire [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471701467) have been written just to get the latter kind of students over this hurdle, and since you seem to belong to the former kind, I don't know if I can convey to you how mystifying the concept is to many people. It isn't even a question of understanding the sequence of steps that happens, more an issue of *believing* that it is possible to use a definition that seems to be not yet complete. The solution involves lots of practice and lots of stepping through some small *and* medium-size examples. Eventually this will let the penny drop for many learners, although by far not all.

Comment: `alloca()` might be good for push operations so that you don't need to have preallocated a local array, but there's usually no `freea()` so I guess that would make `alloca` quite unsuitable for implementing an explicit stack.